# How do I get out of the library in Vault 13 after I completed the first main quest?

Tags: fallout

I just completed the first main quest by giving the water chip to the Overseer. After that I'm automatically send to the Vault 13 library. From there, I can't seem to get out of the library again. There is a dude right before the door (who blocks it) and just says "You are my hero"/"You saved us" etc. I can't reach the door, I can't open it, and there is no other way out. I tried interacting and "using" Science with the computer, but that didn't change anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was just bad luck. I rested until midnight, then all NPCs went to bed and the door was clear to use.

Comment: If you have super stimpaks you could use them.